# how to swap keys into values and values into key in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, swap

guys i want to swap the keys and values in dictionary

my dictionary loook like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
Dictionary<int,int> dic = new Dictionary<int,int>{{1,10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}};
}
```

now iam printing the values form dictionary

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dic)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            Console.ReadKey();
}
```

in display i got this

```
Key = 1, Value = 10
Key = 2, Value = 20
Key = 3, Value = 30
```

i want to swap values between key and value.. after swapping the answer should be like this

```
Key = 10, Value = 1
Key = 20, Value = 2
Key = 30, Value = 3
```

i did lambda expression it changed but i need some other method to do..

Comment: You want to swap the key and value in the actual dictionary? Or just print swapped? "Key = {1}, Value = {0}",

Comment: Are you sure all values are unique (they're not required to be by the dictionary "contract")? If not, how would you like that situation handled?

Comment: What if you had the same value for several keys?

Comment: Not sure why do you want this swap at all. Use dictionary as it is. Are you trying to solve a test?

Comment: i want to swap in actual dictionary @JoshAdams

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever all the values are unique

Comment: @Rafalon plz explain me in this case.. i didn't thought abt same values in diff keys

Comment: @Alpesh exactly

Comment: @Babu my question was nearly the same as the one of Damien. If all values are unique, then you don't have to worry

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think you will understand the below code:

```
namespace Swap
{
public class Class1
{
    public SortedDictionary<string, string> names;

    public void BeforeSwaping()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before Swapping: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        names = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        names.Add("Sonoo", "srinath");
        names.Add("Perer", "mahesh");
        names.Add("James", "ramesh");
        names.Add("Ratan", "badri");
        names.Add("Irfan", "suresh");
        names.Add("sravan", "current");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in names)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void AfterSwaping()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("After Swapping: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        var key = names.Keys;
        var val = names.Values;

        string[] arrayKey = new string[key.Count];
        string[] arrayVal = new string[val.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string s in key)
        {
            arrayKey[i++] = s;
        }
        int j = 0;
        foreach (string s in val)
        {
            arrayVal[j++] = s;
        }
        names.Clear();
        //Console.WriteLine(arrayVal[0] + " " + arrayKey[0]);
        for (int k = 0; k < (arrayKey.Length + arrayVal.Length) / 2; k++)
        {
            names.Add(arrayVal[k], arrayKey[k]);
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> s in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("key:"+s.Key + ", "+"value:" + s.Value);
        }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.BeforeSwaping();
        c.AfterSwaping();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Supposing the values are unique, this can work:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int,int>{{1,10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}};

var dic2 = dic.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x=> x.Key);
```

It won't actually swap the sides, you will get a new dictionary.

Comment: brother i do not want new dictionary to be created. values swap in actual dictionary

Comment: You can't. Why do you think you need that? If both sides are of the same type you can try to add the "swapped" entries after the existing ones and then delete those. But you get nothing at all with that.

Comment: The `Key` is readonly. What you can do is after creating this additional Dictionary, you can clear the original Dictionary and add all entries from the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension so you can do:

```
Dictionary<int, int> newDic = oldDic.SwapKeysAndValues();



    /// <summary>
    /// Take a dictionary and make the values the keys and the keys the values
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="K">The original dictionary key type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="V">The original value type</typeparam>
    /// <param value="dictionary<K, V>"></param>
    /// <returns>Dictionary<V, K></returns>
    public static Dictionary<V, K> SwapKeysAndValues<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> original)
    {
        Dictionary<V, K> result = new Dictionary<V, K>();
        foreach (V value in original.Values.Distinct())
        {
            result.Add(value, original.First(x => x.Value.Equals(value)).Key);
        }

        // optional
        //if(original.Count > result.Count)
        //{
        //  throw new Exception("Duplicate value ignored ");
        //}


        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran speed tests and found creating a new dictionary without specifying the capacity ran slower if there are more than a handful of items. In fact, at 1,000 items it was around 30% slower*. Also if the key and value are the same types, you might also want the same IEqualityComparer to be used in the opposite direction. Finally, if you have a duplicate value, an error will be thrown with the Linq version.

The version here is basically the same as the Linq version with the additions of using the same IEqualityComparer if possible, setting the initial capacity, and preventing potential duplicate errors:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 }, { 3, 30 } };
var dic2 = dic.ToDictionarySwapped();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", dic.Select(i => i.Key + ":" + i.Value)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", dic2.Select(i => i.Key + ":" + i.Value)));

public static Dictionary<V, K> ToDictionarySwapped<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> original, bool useSameComparerIfPossible = true)
{
    IEqualityComparer<V> comparer = null;
    if (useSameComparerIfPossible && typeof(K) == typeof(V)) comparer = (IEqualityComparer<V>)original.Comparer;
    var swapped = new Dictionary<V, K>(capacity: original.Count, comparer: comparer);
    foreach (var item in original) swapped[item.Value] = item.Key;
    return swapped;
}
```

- the test I ran was a loop swapping a dictionary containing 1000 items, 1000 times. The test was repeated with both the capacity being set and the capacity not being set. My average time was around 65ms when the capacity was set, and around 95ms when it was not set. The test was run after being compiled for Release mode.